# Default shell in Oracle Linux?

Tags: shell, oracle-linux

`bash` is default shell for `Red Hat Linux Distribution`. In the same way, what is the default `shell` in Oracle Linux?
I tried to find this by executing

```
[root@serverName ~]# sudo $SHELL
```

But, I did not get any output. So,

- What is the default shell in Oracle Linux?
- Why am I not getting any output of the above command?

Comment: I'm not sure you didn't get any output. You may have gotten the prompt of a new shell. If you type the command line  `echo 1;sudo $SHELL;echo 2` what do you get?

Comment: I got 1 as output.

Comment: Yes... But why did I get `2` as output of exit?

Comment: Here's why: The command line I asked you to try runs 3 commands in sequence. The third command, `echo 2`, does not run until the shell created by `sudo $SHELL` finishes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are already root and you run `sudo $SHELL` it will just run a new instance of the shell on top of the old one and not prompt for a password. You can verify this by typing `exit` or pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>D</kbd> to exit the child shell, again it will appear as if nothing happens.

Try `echo $SHELL` instead.

Comment: I found `/bin/bash` as the output. Also, `sudo $SHELL` initiate a new instance of shell. So, `bash` is the default shell in Oracle Linux too.  Thanks....